# Getting File from .jar using .getResource()

Tags: java, file, jar, getresource

I'm trying to acces a File inside the .jar. In Netbeans, this:

```
System.out.println(new File(this.getClass().getResource("Image.jpg").getFile()).exists());
```

Prints out:

```
true
```

After building however, it prints false.

The file is definitely in the .jar, next to the .class file, and something like this:

```
new Frame(){
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g){
            try{
                g.drawImage(ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("Image.jpg")), 0, 0, this);
            } catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    }.setVisible(true);
```

does paint the image after building.

How can I acces the Image.jpg as a File object?

Answer (score 2):

The file is packed, try

```
resource.getInputStream()
```

or

```
InputStream streamOfYourImg = this.getClass().getRessourceAsStream("com/package/resources/image.jpeg");
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You don't get a File object to it. Its an entry in a JAR not a File on the Filesystem. You have a few options. Create a File by copying the InputStream to the Filesystem, FInd a way to use the InputStream instead, or always have your JAR expanded.